# Save or Move OpenSSL context to continue hash "later" or "elsewhere"

Tags: c, hash, openssl

I'll say up front, that my aim is *not* for security, but rather verifying data integrity.

I want to compute a *standard* hash for several terabytes of data using OpenSSL routines.  The data is logically serialized (i.e. one array of bytes), but is distributed over many computers.

Rather than move the huge dataset to a single process (and memory space) for hashing, I want to pass around the hashing "context" so that the hash computation can take place locally everywhere the data is held.

Another way to frame the problem would be, I want to add bytes to the dataset later and continue the hash computation but result in the same hash answer as though all the bytes were available initially.

I've run into a sticking point, because I can't figure out how the "context" is stored by the library.  I don't know what I would need to pass around or save to accomplish my intent.

(It is safe to assume that all hashing participants will be using the same version of the OpenSSL library.)

I adapted the documentation example to process two chunks of bytes to facilitate discussion.  Now I want to know is there a way to pull the plug on the computer between chunk1 and chunk2 and still get the same answer? Or what if chunk1 and chunk2 are stored on different computers?

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void print_bytes(const unsigned char * bytes, size_t count, const char * prefix)
{
    printf("%s",prefix);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", bytes[i]);
    }
    printf(" (%zd Bytes)\n", count);
}


unsigned int md5_digest_process(const EVP_MD* type, const unsigned char *input, size_t numBytes, unsigned char* hash_out) {
    EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
    unsigned int hash_len = 0;

    size_t chunk1_size = numBytes/2;
    size_t chunk2_size = numBytes - chunk1_size;


    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
    print_bytes( (const unsigned char *)&mdctx, sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX), "EVP_MD_CTX: " );

    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, type, NULL);
    print_bytes( (const unsigned char *)&mdctx, sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX), "EVP_MD_CTX: " );

    // Hash chunk 1:
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, input, chunk1_size);
    print_bytes( (const unsigned char *)&mdctx, sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX), "EVP_MD_CTX: " );

    // Hash chunk 2:    
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, input+chunk1_size, chunk2_size);
    print_bytes( (const unsigned char *)&mdctx, sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX), "EVP_MD_CTX: " );

    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, hash_out, &hash_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);
    return hash_len;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc!=2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "One argument string expected.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    //const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname("MD5");
    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_md5(); //EVP_sha256();
    if(!md) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init MD5 digest\n");
        return 1;
     }


    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];

    const unsigned char * allBytes = (const unsigned char *)argv[1];
    size_t numBytes = strlen(argv[1]); // skip null terminator, consistent with command line md5 -s [string]

    printf("Hashing %zd bytes. EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE is %zd, EVP_MD_CTX size is %zd bytes.\n", numBytes, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE, sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX));

    int hash_len = md5_digest_process(md, allBytes, numBytes, hash);
    print_bytes(hash, hash_len, "Hash: " );

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
$ ./a.out foobar
Hashing 6 bytes. EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE is 64, EVP_MD_CTX size is 48 bytes.
EVP_MD_CTX: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (48 Bytes)
EVP_MD_CTX: 609d9d01010000000000000000000000000000000000000080274062cd7f0000000000000000000040de8e0101000000 (48 Bytes)
EVP_MD_CTX: 609d9d01010000000000000000000000000000000000000080274062cd7f0000000000000000000040de8e0101000000 (48 Bytes)
EVP_MD_CTX: 609d9d01010000000000000000000000000000000000000080274062cd7f0000000000000000000040de8e0101000000 (48 Bytes)
Hash: 3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f (16 Bytes)

$ md5 -s foobar
MD5 ("foobar") = 3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f
```

Since `EVP_MD_CTX` is not changing after each update, I infer that the algorithm state is actually stored elsewhere and I cannot simply copy the 48 EVP_MD_CTX bytes.

I've seen `EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex()` in the manual, but I don't see how to use it for my purpose.

Comment: I made a shallow dive into the `EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex()` [source in digest.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/bbde4740ebcb37ca66d058a0dec1286ed7f8eee7/crypto/evp/digest.c).  There are at least four copies that happen.
    `memcpy(out, in, sizeof(*out));`
    `memcpy(out->md_data, in->md_data, out->digest->ctx_size);`
    `out->pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_dup(in->pctx);`
    `digest->copy(out,in)`

I'm left discouraged that the OpenSSL API supports my desired use.

Comment: Might I investigate the less general (deprecated) API instead of `EVP_*`, use the hard-coded algorithm?